# I need opacity (transparency) for a img with css ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I added the attribute `opacity: .3;` to my `img` tag but it only works for firefox. Is there a solution for firefox and ie8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" alt="Text" class="opac" />

<style>
.opac
{
    opacity:0.3; filter:alpha(opacity=30); height: 150px; width: 150px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ie8 in standards mode you need to use:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
```

Comment: IIRC, the short version works too: -ms-filter:"Alpha(Opacity=30)";

Answer (score 2):

IE uses the `filter` property:

```
filter: alpha(opacity = 30); /* Supported by IE7 and 8 */
```

That should do the same as `opacity: 0.3`