# IE jQuery Opacity Anti-Aliasing Issue

Tags: jquery, css, png, opacity, antialiasing

I am using jQuery to fade in and out a .png images of links on the home page of http://www.logandwight.com

In IE7 and IE8 the text have no anti-aliasing and are all boxy. I've tried messing with the opacity settings and then I tried animating the filter property specifically for IE but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Known issue: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020690/how-to-make-a-google-maps-semi-transparent-png-tile-layer-work-in-ie8/2075524#2075524

Answer (score 1):

This is an inherent problem with IE, transparency, and opacity.  Unfortunately there's no good work around while animating...in this situation I just disable animations for IE users.

Maybe IE9 will finally do something about this?

Answer (score 0):

sIFR might be a possible cross-browser solution here (with a little modification of the sIFR source, you could get those rollover effects).

sIFR is a flash-based font embedding solution that allows you to display real text in a web page using a font of your choosing.

http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr