# jQuery: IE8 bug with animated show()?

Tags: jquery

I was trying out the animated .show(100) of jQuery. The animation works fine in both Firefox and IE8. However, in IE8, the rendered fonts (when animation is used) are thinner than the original font. I retried using .show(), now without the animation, and the rendered text was normal.

here's the jQuery code that handles the animation:

```
var sibling = obj.next();
(sibling.is(":visible")) ? sibling.hide(100) : sibling.show(100);
```

where ***sibling*** is something like this:

```
<div class="tree">
   <ul>
      <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Is this an IE8 bug?

Regards,
Erwin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282576/ie-jquery-opacity-anti-aliasing-issue

Comment: @Māris: ...which links, in turn, to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020690/how-to-make-a-google-maps-semi-transparent-png-tile-layer-work-in-ie8/2075524#2075524

Answer (score 0):

I believe all elements that don't have an opacity of 1 (like while animating) are getting rendered without antialiasing in IE.

There's not much you can do about it.