# Hover effects are not working on IE8, IE7, IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, hover

I am using [Image hover Effect](http://ninodezign.com/cool-image-hover-effect-with-pure-css3/) for a website. After a lot of search and spending long time in customization of that effect, I got the hover effect which I wanted. But that is not properly working on older version of internet explorer version such as IE8, IE7, IE6.

On that website from which I referred has mentioned that these effects only work in modern browsers. You’ll have to provide a suitable fallback if you’d like to support for older browsers.

But I don't know, what should I do to support that for older versions of IE. Also I guess `font-awesome.min.css` not support all browsers which is used in most of image hover effects.

Is it possible to make that hover effect to support all browsers? If yes then how I can do that?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your page on IE7,8,7 problem is those versions of IE will not support

```css
opacity:0.1;
```

see this post about opacity [css opacity not working in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944022/css-opacity-not-working-in-ie7)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately IE support transition from IE10 (http://caniuse.com/#search=transition).

For use Font Awesome with old browser you have to use an old version of FA: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/get-started/

Comment: `<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
<![endif]-->` I have add these line in my `<head>` tag. But still FA icons are not dispalying in IE7. Do i required that `bootstrap.min.css` also to include? what should I do, can you please let me know?

Comment: You use FA with font family? Probably in IE7 doesn't work. In my recent project with support for IE7 i have to use, for example, <i class="icon-plus-sign-alt"></i> and it work perfect.

Comment: i have uploaded the font folder of FA. Can you please mention in your answer what you have done (steps and code required) to work FA on IE7?

Comment: I put this line in <head> section:
`<link href="/PFA/Assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if IE 7]>
        <link href="/PFA/Assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <link href="/PFA/Assets/css/IE7style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <![endif]-->`

The project use bootstrap 2.