# JQuery css opacity on transparent png + IE = dark ugly outlines on transparent pngs

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, transparency, opacity

Not sure what is going on here, but the opacity setting in this line of code is turning my transparent png in IE into an ugly mess.  This wasn't just for IE6 but the newest version of IE as well.  Any ideas?

```
$('#someid.pre').css({margin:'0px', right:'0px', opacity:'1.0'});
```

Comment: This is a known issue. Hang on, I'll find the dupe...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Google Maps semi-transparent PNG tile layer work in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020690/how-to-make-a-google-maps-semi-transparent-png-tile-layer-work-in-ie8)

Comment: your awesome... thanks.  glad to know it wasnt just me.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be setting the background color to white on all of your png background elements.

background: #ffffff url(cta.animated2.png) no-repeat 0 -50px;

But here is another post on the issue from Viget:

http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-ie-png-24-ie-black-background-issue-solved