# How can I make the CSS opacity property work with png images in IE6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, png, opacity

This code works with IE 7 and above, but not with IE6:

```
img.myclass{
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

What should I add to my code?

Thanks

Comment: If your PNG image has alpha transparency, what you show will not work even in IE8! See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020690/how-to-make-a-google-maps-semi-transparent-png-tile-layer-work-in-ie8/).

Comment: Its works for ie7+8 i check it

Comment: if you want us to “check it”, you might want to put a test page up somewhere.

Comment: What’s not working? What are you seeing in IE 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE6 has problems with opacity for png images but look at this and see if it helps:

http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/pngbehavior/pngbehavior.html

Answer (score 1):

What about this? http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/