# positioning and image tranparency failure on IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, positioning

i am trying to put few images on top of another image, and then i am fading in and out those images on top, here's my css:

```
#spark1 {
    bottom: 211px;
    left: 252px;
    position: relative;
    width: 75px;
}
#spark2 {
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 286px;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
}
```

my HTML:

```
<div id="spark1">
    <img src="clientside/images/big_sparkle.png" />
</div>
<div id="spark2">
    <img src="clientside/images/little_sparkle.png" />
</div>
```

my fade effect (in case this has anything to do with the problem i am facing)

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#spark1').fadeOut(800).fadeIn(800);
        $('#spark2').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Everything looks good on firefox and chrome, however on IE 8 (havent tested on any earlier versions of IE), the sparkle images is having a wrong positioning and it has a black background instead of transparent, how can i handle this ?? thanks

Regards

**Update:**

i have tried few css workaround, but nothing seems to work (probably because i am applying it the wrong way :p), but finally i have found a slight convenient solution, i put this line after my jquery fade effect:

```
$("#spark1").css('filter', 'none');
```

and this css to my img:

```
#spark1 img{
        background: transparent;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)";  IE8    
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);    IE6 & 7 */      
        zoom: 1;
    }
```

thanks for [pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) for pointing me out to those articles, i think i am going to stick on to this solution for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PNGs have alpha transparency, there is in fact a bug that persists even in IE8: Images with alpha transparency cannot be made transparent (= given a `opacity` value other than 1).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020690/how-to-make-a-google-maps-semi-transparent-png-tile-layer-work-in-ie8) for background info and workarounds.

Comment: thanks @pekka, i am reading those articles you pointed out at that question, wish me luck