# Problem with jquery opacity and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, opacity

I have the following jQuery code (lizzy-doll is an image):

```
            var toTop = $('.lizzy-doll').css('top');

            $('.lizzy-doll').css('top', '-100px').css('opacity', '0');
            $('.lizzy-doll').animate({
                top : toTop,
                opacity : 1
            }, 2500);
```

This makes my image move down from where it is and fade in and works fine in all browsers except IE, here the image gets a black background (its a transparent png image) instead of fading in (the slide part works fine), I tried adding 'filter' : 'alpha=xx' aswell but same problem.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Google Maps semi-transparent PNG tile layer work in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020690/how-to-make-a-google-maps-semi-transparent-png-tile-layer-work-in-ie8)

Comment: I couldnt make any of the fixes to work, if I do $('#png-img').hide().fadeIn(); though, the black backgrounds stays while its fading but disappears when the img is fully visible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, have you managed to fix this? See if this inserted in the css fixes it:

```
.lizzy-doll { background: none !important; }
```