# jquery png opacity animation problem with ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation, opacity

in this page
http://sitoinanteprima.it/pensieri
i have an opacity animation on the mouse over event on the bi icons.
In ff and chrome it works. but in ie8 when the image appear it's disturbed,

how i can fix it?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Google Maps semi-transparent PNG tile layer work in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020690/how-to-make-a-google-maps-semi-transparent-png-tile-layer-work-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

I got it !

```
style='filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="your image url", sizingMethod="crop"'
```